# How to import numeric ids as strings, to not round value

Tags: r, excel

I have exported from a database a table of values where a few of the columns are unique identifiers. These identifiers are numeric values of length 20.

For example: id=12345678901234567890.

When I export to Excel, these identifiers are rounded. So instead, I have exported as an xml file, and then saved this file in NotePad as csv. The identifiers are intact when I open my file in NotePad, but when I import this file to R, the numbers are again rounded.

How can I import these identifiers to R, while preserving their true "value"?

Is there a way to import all columns of my table as string values?

Comment: Can you check when you import, you made the column type as Integer, obviously length 20 exceeds max capacity of integer

Comment: Perhaps setting the global `options(digits=20)` may help.

Comment: Import them as character values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you import to Excel use the Data ► Get External Data ► From Text command. When the *Text Import Wizard* starts, choose `Delimited` from the first screen and click `Next`. On the second screen, clear all of the delimiters except *comma* and click `Next`. On the third screen, locate and select the import field that holds your unique identifiers and specify a *Column data format* of `Text`. Click `Finish` to complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the class of columns you read in R using the `colClasses` parameter.  This is often a vector of classes, one for each column.  However, if you specify a single class, all columns are read as that class.

```
MyData <- read.table("myfile.csv",sep=',',header=TRUE,colClasses="character")
```

will import all columns as character vectors.